# Change icon for button on VSX Toolbar from C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

We used to have an addin, but now we have a Visual Studio Extension.

When the user clicks on a button on a toolbar, a connection is made with the database. In the addin, the icon on the button then changed to show that a connection was made.

```
 tsbMainConnect.Image = Properties.Resources.connected;
```

When the user clicked on the same button again, the user could disconnect and the button's icon was changed back to the original icon:

```
tsbMainConnect.Image = Properties.Resources.disconnected;
```

So how do I do this in an extension? That is, how do I change what icon the Button should reference in C#, and not in the vsct file?

```
   <Button guid="guidConnectCommandPackageCmdSet" id="ConnectCommandId" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidConnectCommandPackageCmdSet" id="SymToolbarGroup" />
    <Icon guid="ConnectImage" id="bmpConnect1" />
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>Invoke Connect Command</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience and refer [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.menucommand(v=vs.110).aspx), you can change the command Enabled or visibility of the command, but seems that there's no way to change the icon Image.

A workaround is to create two menu buttons, make one of them invisible when it's needed. Follow the steps in the document for how to change the visibility of the command.

[How to: Change the Appearance of a Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166523.aspx)